# WinAPI StartDoc fails for default Adobe PDF when providing DEVMODE

Tags: vba, winapi, printing, gdi

**Objective:** Print text to AdobePDF from multiple sources in Access using WinAPI GDI Print functions. Specifically,

- Get user printer preferences using `PrintDlgEx`

  - Use either of these below to call `StartDoc`

    - `PRINTDLGEX.hDC` **OR**
    - `hDC = CreateDC()`, using the `DEVMODE` outputted from the `PrintDlgEx`

**Problem:** `StartDoc` always returns -1 for hDCs (for Adobe PDF) created using a `DEVMODE` and returns > 0 for all other printers chosen. Is the `DEVMODE` different size or format for Adobe PDF?

**Info:** Here's what I've tried and the results thus far:

- **NEW INFO 8/22/14** Works for PDF when Adobe PDF is *not* my default printer. Works for other printers, regardless of default setting. Why would it only fail when Adobe PDF is default but not fail for other printers?
- **MORE NEW INFO 8/22/14** When Adobe PDF is default, if users clicks another printer and then back on Adobe PDF in the `PrintDlgEx`, it works. *WTF?!? This is getting ridiculous.*
- Identical code works for other printers.
- IsValidDevMode = True.
- Tried multiple different versions of the `DEVMODE` type, all of which seem to work for other printers, but not Adobe PDF.
- When `StartDoc` does return -1, `Err.LastDllError` returns 0.
- When using `CreateDC` with type `DEVMODE` for last parameter, code works for all printers except Adobe PDF.
- Declaring `CreateDC` with type Long for the `DEVMODE` parameter and passing 0 works. But this doesn't incorporate the user's options. The printer defaults are always used.
- Using the `CreateDC` above and then `ResetDC` using the `DEVMODE` from `PrintDlgEx` causes same problem.
- Setting `Application.Printer` settings manually, instead of all of this. Doesn't work.
- Using different `DOCINFO` parameters when Adobe PDF is chosen.

**Code:**

```
Public Function printRawData(objRTB As Object, Optional strFilename As String = "cBasePrint") As Boolean
  Dim hDCPrinter As Long, sDeviceName As String, lJob As Long
  Dim udtDevMode As DEVMODE, udtDocInfo As DOCINFO

  If printPrintDialog(udtDevMode, hDCPrinter) Then
    Debug.Print hDCPrinter, IsValidDevMode(udtDevMode, LenB(udtDevMode)), udtDevMode.dmOrientation, udtDevMode.dmDeviceName

    If hDCPrinter <> 0 Then
        udtDocInfo.pDocName = strFilename
        udtDocInfo.pOutputFile = vbNullString
        udtDocInfo.pDatatype = "RAW"
        udtDocInfo.fType = 0
        udtDocInfo.sSize = LenB(udtDocInfo)

        lJob = StartDoc(hDCPrinter, udtDocInfo)
        Debug.Print lJob, Err.LastDllError

        If lJob > 0 Then
            objRTB.SelPrint hDCPrinter, 0
            EndDoc (hDCPrinter)
        End If

        DeleteDC (hDCPrinter)
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

**Related Questions:**
[Raw Printing Set DevMode options (Orientation, copies, margins, default source, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479740/raw-printing-set-devmode-options-orientation-copies-margins-default-source) 
[How to show printer properties/preferences dialog and save changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437337/how-to-show-printer-properties-preferences-dialog-and-save-changes?rq=1)

**References:** 
[Lessan Vaezi: Printer Settings](http://www.lessanvaezi.com/changing-printer-settings-using-the-windows-api/) Nearly identical code to mine. 
[MS KB: Saving DEVMODE Properties](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167345) Don't want to do this. My `PrintDlgEx` call works and returns a valid `DEVMODE` for other printers. 
[CodeGuru: Printing-using-Win32-Printer](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?494746-Printing-using-Win32-Printer) Identical issue from what I can tell. No answer.
[Adobe PDF Community](https://support.muse.adobe.com/thread/1133296?start=0&tstart=0) Most of the way down the thread, people are having the same issues.

Comment: Get the same issue with another PDF driver. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @MiniScalope I have a deleted answer below but I'm not sure it works. The  DEVMODE struct is missing private data that makes Adobe PDF driver work, which is only populated when the user selects Adobe PDF as a printer manually. My deleted answer attempts to retrieve this private data, but I am unsure if it works, and frankly I think it's BS that it is necessary when doing it the way describe above works for all other printer drivers I've tried. Adobe just needs to be special >:(

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's not too late. But I found a solution by studying some sample MFC projects created by MS

```cpp
        // Determine name of Adobe PDF Printer if installed.
        CString AdobePrinterName = L"";
        DWORD cbNeeded, cReturned;
        EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, NULL, 2, NULL, 0, &cbNeeded, &cReturned);
        PRINTER_INFO_2* pPrinterInfo = (PRINTER_INFO_2*)malloc(cbNeeded);
        EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, NULL, 2, (LPBYTE)pPrinterInfo, cbNeeded, &cbNeeded, &cReturned);
        for (int i = 0; i < cReturned; i++) {
            if (wcscmp(pPrinterInfo[i].pDriverName, L"Adobe PDF Converter") == 0) {
                // Adobe PDF printer is found
                AdobePrinterName = pPrinterInfo[i].pPrinterName;
                break;
            }
        }

        int started = 0;
        // start the print document
        if (po->printerName.CompareNoCase(AdobePrinterName) == 0) {

            // This is a work around for printing to Adobe PDF printer.
            DOCINFO docInfo;
            memset(&docInfo, 0, sizeof(DOCINFO));
            docInfo.cbSize = sizeof(DOCINFO);
            docInfo.lpszDocName = L"_untitle"; // <-- Adobe PDF printer needed this to work properly
            started = dc.StartDoc(&docInfo);
        }
        else {
            started = StartDoc(&dc, po);
        }

        if (!started)
        {
            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            goto fail;
        }
```

Comment: I'll review and see if it works for my use case.  Need to convert to VBA. Might be a bit before I can say this is the answer.